# Unable to run Coturn

Tags: webrtc, ubuntu-14.04, stun

I am building a WebRTC app and I am using [Coturn](https://code.google.com/p/coturn/) as a TURN server. The problem is that after installing it (using gdebi as instructed in the docs), I am unable to run the service.
I have enabled the service in the `/etc/default/coturn` file, but then when I run `service coturn start` it says `[OK]` but the service is not running (I check this with `service --status-all`).

The log files `/var/log/turn_*.log` show no errors, I have no idea how to troubleshoot this, I've tried the same steps on a Vagrant machine and it works fine.

Additional infos:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Coturn 4.1.2.1-1

Anyone knows how to fix this or how I can find out what is causing it?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to run as standalone binary executing `turnserver` file?

Comment: Well after reinstalling it on a different machine it worked like a charm so my guess is that something on that particular setup was somehow conflicting with it.